# Android JSON Error Reading Username

Tags: android, json, authentication

**This is my php script and it works fine**

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "aaaa", "bbbb");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("login", $con);
  $u = $_GET['username'];
  $p = $_GET['password'];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE password = '$p' AND username = '$u' ") or die('Errant query:');
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output = $row;
  }
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close($con);
} else {
  $output = "not found";
  print(json_encode($output));
}
```

**This is what my php script returns**

```
{"username":"mohamed"}
```

**This is login activity**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    InputStream webs = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    String url = "http://localhost/login.php?username=";
    EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    url = url + user.getText().toString() + "&password=" + pass.getText().toString();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
      response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      webs = entity.getContent();
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
      webs.close();
      result = sb.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String res = result;
    Button lgn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lgn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);
          if (json.getString("username").equals("mohamed")) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
          } else {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Reading username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          t.show();
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Toast appears with "Error Reading username"**

there is manifest Internet permission

android 4.2.2

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `\n` from while loop no need to edit this as break line just read as it is.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
      sb.append(line);
}
```

This will change your json with `\n` and when you parsing this, this will throw the exception because it not valid form. As per your response after editing with `\n` will be getting as

```
{"username":"mohamed"}\n // so here this will invalid json format
```

Comment: the error in creating JSON object from the string result but I don't know why :(

Comment: one more thing use AsyncTask for calling any webservice request in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

That is example for how i deal with php and json, hope it helps you :

php:

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable ");

 $info=array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

      array_push($info,$row);
    }

 echo json_encode($info);
```

android:

web service part:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray;
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 String url = "http://myurl.com/myphpfile.php";
 HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

 try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);
    final String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);




} catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

decoding json part:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject;
 String id,user,pswd;
 try{
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     id = jsonObject.getString("ID");
     user = jsonObject.getString("username");
    pswd = jsonObject.getString("password");

}

 }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

## Notes:

== Direct usage for webservices will cause error in 4.0 phones, you have to use async task, put the web services part in the doinbackground section.
== You can change the code to match the fields of your table, the webservices method you need (post or get) ....